# Как получить дату из устройства без часов и месяцев и лет

Tags: java, android

Требуется получить дату у устройства, без часов и месяцев и лет. После получения даты требуется загрузить определённый xml файл(разметка). Но при запуске на устройстве-вылетает(краш).

```
public class Eng_lvl extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int curTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl10);
        StartAnimations();

        String curStringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(curTime);
        if (curTime == 10) {
            setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
        }
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans2);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView l = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars2);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans5);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView B = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars3);
        B.clearAnimation();
        B.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: Что делать, [когда кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос вместо *"спасибо, заработало"*

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы `SimpleDateFormat` отработал правильно, в метод `format` нужно передать объект `Date` с текущей датой, а не `int`, который вы даже не инициализировали явно, и поэтому в нём значение по умолчанию 0.

```
String curStringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
if (curStringDate.equals("10")) {
    setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
}
```

А лучше сделать ещё проще, без форматирования дат:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//noinspection WrongConstant
if (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 10) {
    setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
}
```

Comment: Календарь это самое верное решение для этого случая!

Comment: Спасибо!Всё заработало!

Answer (score 0):

```
String curStringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(curTime);
```

вы не заполнили значение параметра curTime
вам нцжно сначала сделать что-то подобное:

```
curTime = someValue;
```

а уже потом

```
String curStringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(curTime);
```

Comment: someValue становится красным(Cannot resolve symbol someValue)